# How to change widget parameters on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a widget in my page to get some data that I call like this:

```
<div id="widgetContain">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.com/widgetscript.js" async>
            {
                "a": "1m",
                "b": 425,
                "c": "light",
                "d": false,
                "e": 450,
                "f": "blue",
                "g": true,
                "g": "en"
            }
          </script>
</div>
```

beside that, I have some links that when clicked on I need to change the "f" value.

```
<p><a href="" data-href="red" class="ttlink active">Red</a></p>
```

I don't know how to make this work. I tried making the value for "f" a var:

```
{
    ....
    "f":newVal;
}
$('.ttlink').on('click', function(e){
     var newVal = $(this).attr('data-href');
});
```

And that obviously doesn't work. How do I load the script and then the key / value pairs as parameters and modify them on click of link while only loading the library once?

Fiddle that works per the api author's intended use - https://jsfiddle.net/35u247xc/

Fiddle that has setup I need -> https://jsfiddle.net/5gar867m/1/

Comment: AFAIK a `<script>` tag can be external: `<script src='//sub.domain.top/path/to/file.js'></script>` or inline `<script> var example = "value"; function getValue(example) {...</script>`. I don't recall `<script>` tags exhibiting both qualities. [*"If a `script` element has a `src` attribute specified, **it should not have a script embedded inside its tags** since it can lead to unexpected behavior."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) [emphasis mine]

Comment: I don't disagree - however this is how the widget is set up per the API author -> https://www.tradingview.com/widget/technical-analysis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="widgetContain">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.com/widgetscript.js" async></script>
  </div>
  <!-- end of page -->
  <script>
    var params = {
      a: "1m",
      b: 425,
      c: "light",
      d: false,
      e: 450,
      f: "blue",
      g: true,
      h: "en"
    };
    $('.ttlink').on('click', function(e) {
      params.f = $(this).data("href");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

The external library will be loaded and after all content is loaded, then the second script block will be run.

**Update**

Can try a different order.

```
<body>
  <div id="widgetContain">
    <script>
    var params = {
      a: "1m",
      b: 425,
      c: "light",
      d: false,
      e: 450,
      f: "blue",
      g: true,
      h: "en"
    };
    $('.ttlink').on('click', function(e) {
      params.f = $(this).data("href");
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.com/widgetscript.js" async>
      params
    </script>
  </div>
  <!-- end of page -->
</body>
```

This defines the Object called `params` first, then binds a callback to click, and then when the widget loads, the Object can be loaded with it. Note, this will only load once upon page load and changes made will not effect the widget after page load.

Comment: I used console.log(params) and it showed the key / values as expected. However, I need it to run inside the <script> tag as shown in my example. I get this error on load and its not re-submitting with the params on click - "Widget settings parse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign your example is not complete and it's unclear what you need to have "run". Your example just defines an unnamed Object inside the script block.

Comment: question is updated with two fiddle links. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

set them to a variable

```
let params = { "a": "1m", "b": 425,
"c": "light", "d": false,
"e": 450, "f": "blue",
"g": true, "g": "en" };
```

and change the values

```
$('.ttlink').on('click', function(e){
     params.b = $(this).attr('data-href');
});
```

the script element is not modifiable

Comment: So in the initial load I would have: <div id="widgetContain">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.com/widgetscript.js" async>
            {
                let params = { "a": "1m", "b": 425,
                "c": "light", "d": false,
                "e": 450, "f": "blue",
                "g": true, "g": "en" };
            }
          </script>
</div>

Comment: On load I get this error "embed-widget-technical-analysis.js:1 Widget settings parse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0" then on click of the link I get this error "main.js?ver=20151215:105 Uncaught ReferenceError: params is not defined"

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign it would not be inside the `{` and `}`. It would be `var params = {}` or `let params = {}` inside the `<script></script>` section.

Comment: RobinSeerig & @Twisty - question updated with some fiddle links to show how it works out of the box and how I would like to modify it.